# SQL converting date/time to unix timestamp

Tags: sql, string, ssis, sql-server-2016, unix-timestamp

im running an SSIS job that is pulling in multiple string columns into a SQL sever 2016 database, however i need to create a row index so that my job knows when to get new data. i have a date/time string column that im pulling in. i want to convert this to a unix timestamp so that i can use that in my code for when to grab new data.

is there a way to do this?  my string column with the date/time that im pulling in looks like this:
'2020.07.29 08:43:53' '2021.05.03 12:50:22' etc..

what would be the best way to convert all the strings in my 'datetime' column to unix timestamps?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the string to a `datetime` using:

```
select convert(datetime, '2021.05.03 12:50:22')
```

You can then convert this to Unix epoch time (seconds since 1970-01-01) using:

```
select datediff(second, '1970-01-01', convert(datetime, '2021.05.03 12:50:22'))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2fd8a13eea517f2423aab9bc71872f9b) is a db<>fiddle.